# Parameter emp_name was not defined for stored procedure get_empoyee_details

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stored-procedures

Am a bit confused,  am trying to call a stored procedures using spring boot JPA. Have created a simple procedure and call the procedure using JPA’s @NamedStoredProcedureQuery annotation.

For some wierd reason am getting an error

> Parameter emp_name was not defined for stored procedure
> get_empoyee_details.
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError

what am i doing wrong, have tried to go through other answers on stackoverflow no help

this is my entity class

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data
@ToString
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "get_empoyee_details", procedureName = "get_empoyee_details", resultClasses = {
        Employee.class }, parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "emp_name", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class) })
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "employee_code")
    private String employeeCode;
}
```

my controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getEmp(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name) {
        List<Employee> employees = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("get_empoyee_details")
                .setParameter("emp_name", name).getResultList();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

stack trace

```
Error preparing registered callable parameter] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Parameter emp_name was not defined for stored procedure get_empoyee_details.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
```

my stored procedure for sql server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_empoyee_details @name nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE employee_name = @name
GO
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli have added the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name is wrong as the excpetion says.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
    Parameter emp_name was not defined forstored procedure get_empoyee_details.
```

Change it to name:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "get_empoyee_details", 
                          procedureName = "get_empoyee_details", 
                          resultClasses = { Employee.class }, 
                          parameters = {
                              @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "name", // this was wrong
                                                        mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class) })
public class Employee {
```